# How to set the content-type, when uploading to Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mime-types, tar, google-cloud-build

When uploading an `*.tar.gz` build artifact to Cloud Storage bucket, it wrongfully applies MIME type `application/tar`, while it would have to apply MIME type `application/tar+gzip` (or the official MIME type `application/gzip`), in order to be able to download and extract the uploaded  `*.tar.gz` archive then again. This only works, when I manually set the MIME type afterwards (in the object details), but I'd be looking for a way, to define the proper MIME type right away. How this can be done?

The `cloudbuild.yaml` which produces the issue roughly looks alike this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |-
      - tar -zcf ./test_${SHORT_SHA}.tar.gz ./$_UPLOAD_DIRNAME
    env:
      - '_UPLOAD_DIRNAME=$_UPLOAD_DIRNAME'
      - 'SHORT_SHA=$SHORT_SHA'
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://some-bucket/'
    paths: ['*.tar.gz']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading: [Working With Object Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata), it turned out that the `artifacts` node won't suffice.
`gsutil` seems to be the only way to explicitly pass the desired MIME type `application/tar+gzip`:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |-
        tar -zcf ./test_${SHORT_SHA}.tar.gz ./$_UPLOAD_DIRNAME
        gsutil -h "Content-Type:application/tar+gzip" cp ./test_${SHORT_SHA}.tar.gz ${_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET}
        gsutil ls -L ${_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET}test_${SHORT_SHA}.tar.gz
    env:
      - '_UPLOAD_DIRNAME=$_UPLOAD_DIRNAME'
      - '_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET=$_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET'
      - 'SHORT_SHA=$SHORT_SHA'
```